# Type Error Undefined, getting this error when setting state not too sure why

Tags: reactjs

So trying to do an api call and then set state based on the output of the json however I create the object but I can't set that object to the state. I've done something similar in a different react component and it works fine.

TypeError: data is undefined

```
import { Bar, Line, Pie, Scatter } from "react-chartjs-2";

class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      test: {}
    };
  }

  getPredictionData = company => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_predict_price/" + company)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        var values = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
          values = values.concat({ x: json[i][0], y: json[i][1] });
        }
        console.log(values);

        var predictData = {
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Stock Prices",
              data: values,
              showLine: true,
              pointRadius: 0,
              borderColor: "blue",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"
            }
          ]
        };

        console.log(predictData);
        this.setState({
          test: predictData
        });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPredictionData(this.props.title);
  }

  render() {       
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        {" "}
        <Scatter
          data={this.props.chartData}
          ....
```

Output of console:

Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
Object { datasets: (1) […] }

Comment: Doesn't look like you're trying to access anything called `data` that caused your error message.  Maybe include the part of code that is directly bringing up that error? I'm guessing that you're trying to access the state before it's been set in your chain of `then`s.

Comment: on which particular line you are getting this error? There is no `data` in your code. Are you using your state in render? Can you share that too?

Comment: In the error message its highlighting the set state line in getPredictionData function, I've edit the post to show the rest of the code. I've just added my render but its just configuring the graph.

Comment: Looks like your prop `chartData is undefined`

Comment: thanks figured it out. Its because I was initializing my chartData with null, if it set it to an empty object then I no longer get the error.